# Probability of finding a rejection in a sample

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-distribution

What is the probability that I find a rejection in 20 samples inspected if the total population is 234 and there are 11 rejections?

Comment: If this is a homework question, then please add the "self-study" tag, and explain what you've tried so far, so that we can understand where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Work question. Need to fight a government inspector.

Answer (score 1):

You might've figured it out from the new tag on your question, but it might be appropriate to use the Hypergeometric distribution for this.

Say the number of rejections you come up with is denoted as $X$. If your population is of size $N=234$, and if out of these, there are $K=11$ objects that can be classified as "rejections", then the probability of finding exactly $k=1$ rejection in $n=20$ samples is 
$$
P(X=k; n,N,K) = \frac{{K \choose k}{N-K \choose n-k} }{{N \choose n} } = 0.3945663.
$$

Comment: That is extremely helpful thank you. I'll have to do a bit of homework on hypergeometric distributions.